# Inner functions in python and branch counting by pylint

Tags: python, pylint

**Inner function in pythons gives us following benifits:**

- Provides encapsulation at function level.
- Gives access to enclosing scope variables, without passing as arguments.
- Avoids pollution in larger namespace
- Allows us to add a wrapper over functions/classes (decorators)

A single function can have multiple inner functions.

pylint counts branches in a function. If a function has multiple inner functions then the count will be aggregated branch-count value of all the inner function as well as outer function.

**Do we have any config option in pylint to not aggregate the inner function branch counts?**

If yes, then please let me know and ignore rest of the post.

Rational behind limiting branch count might be one of these:

- Function is doing more than one thing.
- Code became too complex to read.

Inner function is already dealing with these things (along with its own benefits)

- There are separation of concerns in the form of inner functions.
- Code is still simple and easy to understand.

**Then why pylint is aggregating these counters?**

Answer (score 0):

Pylint use mac cabe for the cyclomatic complexity. Not counting the inner function was deemed to be at odd with  the spirit of what the the mac cabe metrics is doing [in this issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/mccabe/issues/60).

> Based on the spirit of the calculation (i.e., to reduce the complexity of routines - a.k.a, functions) I'm starting to wonder if adding the flag would counteract the benefits of running mccabe. Specifically, nested functions might not contribute to logical branches in a function, however, they do contribute to the complexity as far as other people are considered when reading the same code. Further, if you look at mccabe [as a calculation of the number of different tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity#Implications_for_software_testing) you might need to write to exercise all the code inside a routine/function, then you must consider nested functions as well.